# how to display dynamic data as selected in ng-select with search dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngselect

```
let options= \[{value: 'a', id:1},{value:'b',id:2}\];

let items=\[\];
```

I will be binding this data to ng select with search in ng-options

```
<ng-select [items]="options"
  bindLabel="value"
  bindValue="value"
  [multiple]="true"
  placeholder="Search for..."
  [(ngModel)]="items"
  (change)="changeFn($event,false)"
  [hideSelected]="true"
  
  >
<ng-template
        ng-option-tmp
        let-item="item"
        let-item$="item$"
        let-index="index"
      >
        <div class="row">
            <span class="text-muted" >Task filter: {{ item['value'] }}</span>
        </div>
      </ng-template>

            
</ng-select>
```

on click of a button i wanted to push some dynamic data like

```
function(){
   this.item.push({value: 'c', id:3}\];  
}
```

i wanted to display **value  c** as selected in the ng-select how can i make that possible

i have no idea how to make it work. can anyone help me to make it work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When adding new item as option, you want that item to be auto-selected right?

Comment: yes, i wanted item as a auto selected

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation (Change Detection section)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select),

> Ng-select component implements OnPush change detection which means the dirty checking checks for immutable data types.

You should update the array's value for both `options` and `items` instead of performing object mutation.

```
add() {
  this.options = [...this.options, { value: 'c', id: 3 }];
  this.items = [...this.items, 'c'];
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-itgyat?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 different techniques here.

1. Run change detection forcefully after making changes in your object.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

2. Use change detection strategy onPush, here even if you make changes in inside object then change Detection will run automatically.

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnChanges, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "app-your-component",
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ["./your-component.component.scss"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class YourComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit  {}
```

3. You can also reassigned modified object using spread operator

```
add() {
  this.options = [...this.options, { value: 'c', id: 3 }];
  this.items = [...this.items, 'c'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way that works for me,
just refresh items in your function adding

```
function(){
this.items.push({value: 'c', id:3}];
//add here 
this.items = this.items.slice();
}
```